# Accelerometer integration for a table mouse

Tags: filter, mouse, signal-processing, accelerometer, noise-reduction

I want to use an accelerometer to measure displacement on a table, so to build a table mouse based on it.
I have been trying a few devices and the most suitable seems to be Kionix KXTF9 (12bit) and Freescale MMA8451 (14bit), this last expecially.

I have also tried several data processing chains and filtering combinations: in particular a) simple thresholding for eliminating the noise floor, b) integration with constancy check to avoid drift, c) Kalman filtering, d) running averages, e) straight LP and HP filtering, etc..

My main issue is not actually estimating distance int he direction of movement, but the noise that originates on the other axis (like an increased noise floor) and which causes a significant "movement" to be "felt" also on the axis other than the one it's moving along.

Have you ever faced such an issue and have any hint to share?

Comment: (a) This is hard. (b) You might ask over on dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I'm curious. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I did some research but it led to no interesting result. It appears to be too sensitive to spurious movements.